# What dishes pair well with orange wine?

Tags: wine, pairing

What food stuffs pair well with **orange wine**?

This website has a little information on orange wines: [Crushing: Orange Wines](http://blog.cookingchanneltv.com/2010/10/19/orange-wine-in-time-for-halloween/).

But what I would like to know is what foods go well with these orange wine and why they are paired as such?

Comment: This is a non answer, but I would say anything that pairs well with a Rose'. Orange wines were a fad about 5 years ago, but I don't see much anymore.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

1. Orange wine + sheeps cheese.

The cheese is rich, gooey, it'll support the sweetness of orange wine. I think it's better with a mature sheeps cheese like an aged Pecorino/Manchego.

2. Orange wine + apple pie/apfel gratin/apfelstrudel.

Hahaha, inspired by my half-German half-Indonesian father. Being a seasonal vegetarian is kinda cool. You'll be the coolest vegetarian on earth.

3. Orange wine + Indonesian Kambing Guling (slow roasted young lamb shanks with Indonesian spices, herbs).

Trust me the delicate meat of young lamb was born just to accompany orange wine. The spices, the herbs, the fat, will balance the structure of the wine. Here are some resources about Indonesian Bumbu/seasoning:

[Bumbu seasoning (Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bumbu_(seasoning))

[Indonesian Herbs and Spices](http://www.welove-indonesia.com/blog/spices-in-indonesia/)

[Herbs and Spices The most important part of Indonesian cooking](http://www.discover-java-and-bali.com/herbs-and-spices.html)

4. Orange wine + seafood + lemon + sliced/chopped raw onion.

Helping your seafood addiction whilst battling cholesterol (thank me later). The sour lemon will soften the wine somewhat. What about the taste? So precious that its value can't be determined.

Answer (score 1):

First of all what can we say about **orange wines**.

> Not only is their orange hue fitting for the season, but they tend to be heavier than whites and lighter than reds - a perfect compromise for the fall. Make sure to serve it slightly chilled, at around 55 degrees Fahrenheit, and try pairing it with those increasingly heavier fall meals, like roasted vegetables and poultry.  - [Crushing: Orange Wines](http://blog.cookingchanneltv.com/2010/10/19/orange-wine-in-time-for-halloween/).

Here is what Jared Brandt says about orange wines:

> "Orange wines fill in the gaps when pairing, because you get the acidity of a white and the tannins of a red," says Jared Brandt of Donkey & Goat winery in Berkeley, California. Last fall, he and his wife, Tracey, released a cloudy orange wine: a floral, spicy Roussanne. "We recently had a tofu dish that a red wine would have obliterated, and a **rich lamb dish** that would have overwhelmed a white," Brandt says. He opted to pair both with an orange wine from Friuli's Stanko Radikon, one of Gravner's acolytes, and it worked brilliantly.
>
> Some people might argue that rosé can be just as versatile with food as an orange wine. Pax Mahle, who makes an orange Pinot Gris under his Wind Gap Wines label, replies that orange wines are funkier tasting (and thus more interesting) than rosés. "Rather than something that goes with your picnic, orange wines go with your **truffle pasta**," he says. Essentially, the wines have umami. - [Ancient  Wine Techniques, Simple Dishes](http://www.foodandwine.com/articles/)

Matthew Latkiewicz has these foods to pair with orange wine:

> But here’s what to do: Drink some orange wine along with food. Orange wines are all over the place from a flavor standpoint, so there’s no go-to rule for pairing it, but unlike a lot of white wines, which get bowled over by strong food flavors, orange wine has the structure and acidity from the skins to stand up to strong dishes while still retaining the spectrum of white-wine flavors. Without getting too wonky about the pairing-speak, know that you can also ditch fish-with-white, meat-with-red thinking; orange wine is a lot more versatile. For example, a bottle of Angiolino Maule Sassaia, which tastes almost nutty, can holds its own against something like **grilled hanger steak**; and that Vinujancu had a lot of qualities of a funky craft beer; it’d be great at cutting through fatty dishes — or **anything with bacon**. - [Sloshed: How to Enjoy Orange Wine, the Indie Darling of the Wine World](http://www.grubstreet.com/2012/08/what-is-orange-wine-sloshed.html)

Here is yet another blog has to say that might be of interest to some:

> Orange wine is a bit of a misnomer because it isn’t referring to a wine made with oranges nor is it a Mimosa cocktail (a blend of 1 part orange juice to 2 parts sparkling wine.) Orange wine is something entirely different.
>
> Because of their boldness, orange wines pair excellently with bolder foods including **curry dishes, Moroccan cuisine, Ethiopian cuisine** (like those **spongelike pancakes called Injera**), **Korean dishes with fermented kimchi such as bibim bap**, and **traditional Japanese cuisine** including fermented soybeans (Natto). Due to high phenolic content (tannin and bitterness) along with the nutty tartness, orange wines **pair with a wide variety of meats from beef to fish.** - [All About Orange Wine](http://winefolly.com/review/orange-wine/)

Comment: I would pair orange wine with a duck filet cooked with blackcurrent, in the fall time...

Answer (score 1):

An orange desert wine such as Quady Essensia pairs well with chocolate deserts.